# Argparse official way for disabling other option if one option is selected

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I intent to give different behaviors that are not related each other if `-r` is
given or not given. So, if `-r` argument present, it will take two and only
two. If not, it will eat all given argument. With this setup:

```
parser = ArgumentParser(prog='frog')
parser.add_argument('integer',
                    metavar='integer(s)',
                    type=int,
                    nargs='*')
parser.add_argument('-r', '--range',
                    metavar=('start', 'end'),
                    type=int,
                    nargs=2)
```

if I call:

```
frog -r 123 1231 121
# this will give Namespace(integer=[123], range=[1231, 121])
```

if I change `nargs` for `integer` to `*`, and then call:

```
frog -r 123 1231
# complaints about 'integer' that is required
```

Of course it is not too complicated to create simple args checking. But, my question is, is `argparse` has official way to disable one option if another one is activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if I change nargs for integer to *, and then call:` - I think you mean, `change nargs for integer to +`.  In your example, it is already *.

With the '+', `integer` expects to find at least one argument.  If nothing is left over from `-r`, then it is going to complain.

The basic philosophy of `argparse` is to handle each argument independently.  It also tries to be order independent, so `frog 123 -r 1231 32` will work just as well as `frog -r 1231 32 123`.

It is possible to force interactions between arguments with custom `Action` classes, but that tends to destroy the order independence.

Usually it is best to write the arguments to accept the most general situation, and do your own checking afterwards.  Thus I'd stick with `*`, and object if `args.integer` is the wrong number of values.

The primary purpose of `argparse` is to figure out what the user wants - it's a parser.  You can always scold them afterwards.